# How to assert a failed API call as a passed test

Tags: karate

I have what seems to be a simple problem yet I can't find the solution.

I want to write a negative test script that verifies that a certain secured service is inaccessible. I.e when I do the GET on it, it fails as expected.

I do something like the following:

```
        Given url 'www.secreturl.com'
        And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        When method GET
        Then match responseStatus == error

I get the following response:
java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known
http call failed after 1157 milliseconds for url: https://secreturl.com
```

So Karate throws an error before it can ever get to the responseStatus. Is there a way to catch this error and assert it?